# How to make a custom class work with the ‘for in’ loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, for-loop

If I have a custom class, how can I make it work with a ‘for in’ loop, like this:

```
class number_range:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.__data = []
        for i in range(start, end):
            self.__data.append(i)
    #something that will allow the for in loop

numbers = number_range(1, 100)          
for number in numbers:
    print(number)
```

Comment: You need to build an [Iterator](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-iterator-tutorial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is an iterator. For example, this one acts like range but only gives you odd numbers:

```
class oddrange(object):
    def __init__(self, first, lastPlusOne):
        # Ensure start at first odd >= given start, store terminator.

        self.__curr = first + 1 - first % 2
        self.__term = lastPlusOne

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # Terminate if range over, otherwise return current, calculate next.

        if self.__curr >= self.__term:
            raise StopIteration()

        (cur, self.__curr) = (self.__curr, self.__curr + 2)
        return cur
```

You can see this in action with the calling code:

```
for i in oddrange(-5, 9): print(i, end = ' ')
print()
for i in oddrange(-3, 9): print(i, end = ' ')
print()
for i in oddrange(-4, 10): print(i, end = ' ')
print()
for i in oddrange(-4, 10): print(i, end = ' ')
print()
```

This generates:

```
-5 -3 -1 1 3 5 7
-3 -1 1 3 5 7
-3 -1 1 3 5 7 9
-3 -1 1 3 5 7 9
```

---

Note that this is *not* compatible with Python 2 as many examples on the net are. I think it's well past time we all accept the fact that Python 2 is done, and move on :-)

If you really *do* need it, you can just add this to the class:

```
def next(self): return self.__next__()
```

Comment: The question is tagged Python 3, so you probably don't even have to bother with the Python 2 caveat. :)